# Create a reverse of the CSS class

Tags: css

i have a CSS styling class can anyone help me out to create the reverse of this .
Below is the code:

```
.w3-animate-right{
    position:relative;
    animation:animateright 0.4s}@keyframes animateright{from{right:-200px;opacity:0} to{right:0;opacity:1}}
```

Thanks if anyone can help me out to animate the thing in opposite direction from above.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. This site is for questions specific to Salesforce. Whilst you may be facing this issue in implementing an LWC or Aura component, this is a question better targeted at a different forum specializing in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Just add an [animation-direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction):

```
.w3-animate-right {
  position: relative;
  animation: animateright 0.4s;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}
```